# TikZ ER-Diagram double edge looks ugly

Tags: tikz-pgf

Drawing an ER-Diagram in TikZ and using double edges results in ugly connections of those edges into the nodes. What can be done to connect those edges nicely to other nodes?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, er}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node [entity, double distance=1.5pt] (test) {Test};
\node [attribute, right=of test] {TestID} edge (test);
\node [attribute, double distance=1.5pt, left=of test] {Attribute} edge[double distance=1.5pt] (test);
\node [relationship, below=of test] (test2) {Test} edge[double distance = 1.5pt] (test);
\node [relationship, double distance=1.5pt, below left=of test] (test3) {Test} edge[double distance = 1.5pt] (test);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reducing the `1.5pt` to, let's say, `0.8pt` in all occurrences makes the connections "less ugly", but does not fix the underlying problem.

Comment: You could replace the `double distance` options at nodes with `Double` defined as `Double/.style={double distance=#1, outer sep=.5*(#1)}, Double/.default=1.5pt` which will adjust the border to inner side of the black border. This works best for orthogonal connections and for rectangular nodes. For everything else this all seems like a hack.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problems

There are two problems here:

1. Due to `double` the default outer seps don't work correctly in putting the shape's border on the outside of the double line.
2. The `double` lines are really just that: a line that is drawn twice, one a very thick (`<double distance> + 2 \pgflinewidth`) black line and then a thinner (just `<double distance>`) white line above it.

   They have the same problem as all thick lines that don't connect to nodes orthogonally to their border.

   The picture

   ```
   \tikz\graph[nodes={line width=5pt, draw}, edges={red, line width=5pt}]{
     a -- b[xshift=5mm];
     c -- d -- {a, b};
   };
   ```

   will result in
   [image]

   The connection `a -- b` and `c -- d` look good, `a -- d` we could accept but `b -- d` is just bad.

#### Solutions

Point 1 can be easily solved: Set the outer seps to `.5*<double distance> + \pgflinewidth`.

For point 2, I'd suggest placing the edges behind the nodes and use a rect line cap:

```
\tikz[graphs/edges={red, line width=5pt}]
  \graph[nodes={line width=5pt, draw}]{
     a -- b[xshift=5mm];
     c -- d
   } [behind path] graph[use existing nodes, edges={line cap=rect}]{
     d -- {a, b}
   };
```

[image]

This will only work well if the line width of the edges isn't bigger than the line width of the nodes:
[image]

And in fact, the same will happen to the not-doubled node:
[image]

While we could in this specific case just shorten the edge by `sqrt(2)*<double distance+2\pgflinewidth` instead of using the rect line cap, the most straight forward general solution would be

1. have all nodes be filled with white: `fill = white`,
2. put all edges on the background and
3. use the rect line cap: `line cap=rect`.

This works well enough for

- placing nodes on white background and
- straight lines.

For curved lines it might be needed to use a negative shorten amount (see 3rd diagram).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, er, graphs}
\tikzset{
  edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}},
  Double/.style={double distance={#1}, outer sep=.5*(#1)+\pgflinewidth},
  Double/.default=1.5pt}
\begin{document}
\tikz[font=\footnotesize, dbl/.style=Double]
  \node [entity,       dbl]              (test) {Test}
   node [attribute,              right=of test] {TestID}    edge (test)
   [edges=Double]
   node [attribute,    dbl,       left=of test] {Attribute} edge (test)
   node [relationship,           below=of test] {Test}      edge (test)
   node [relationship, dbl, below left=of test] {Test}      edge (test);

\tikz[font=\footnotesize, dbl/.style=Double, nodes={fill=white}]
  \node [entity,       dbl]                     (test)  {Test}
   node [attribute,              right=of test] (id)    {TestID} edge (test)
   node [attribute,    dbl,       left=of test] (attr)  {Attribute}
   node [relationship,           below=of test] (test2) {Test}
   node [relationship, dbl, below left=of test] (test3) {Test}
   [behind path]
   graph[use existing nodes, edges={line cap=rect}]{
     test --[Double] {attr, test2, test3}
   };
\tikz[font=\footnotesize, dbl/.style=Double, nodes={fill=white}]
  \node [entity,       dbl]                     (test)  {Test}
   node [attribute,              right=of test] (id)    {TestID} edge (test)
   node [attribute,    dbl,       left=of test] (attr)  {Attribute}
   node [relationship,           below=of test] (test2) {Test}
   node [relationship, dbl, below left=of test] (test3) {Test}
   [behind path]
   graph[use existing nodes, edges={line cap=rect}]{
     test --[bend left, Double, shorten <=-1.5pt] {attr, test2, test3}
   };
\end{document}
```

### Output (2nd diagram)

[image]

Comment: Mathematically speaking, there are much nicer solutions possible by drawing two seperate lines after finding their intersections with the nodes' borders but that's a lot of work and is not necessary unless filling with white or any other background color is not feasable.